# Getting Out of Memory Error onPictureTaken BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray

Tags: android, bitmap, camera, out-of-memory

I am getting a weird OOM error on decoding the bytearray I get when taking a picture. My code is as below. Please tell if there is a better way to do it.

```
@Override
public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    // TODO something with the image data

    // Restart the preview and re-enable the shutter button so that we can take another picture
    camera.startPreview();
    inPreview = true;
    shutterButton.setEnabled(true);
    System.gc();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(data , 0, data.length);
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(90);
    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(),
            bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, false);
    if(bitmap != null){
        boolean fileSaved = Funcs.saveImage(getActivity(),resizedBitmap, "moizali");
        if(fileSaved){
            ((BaseActivity)getActivity()).goToPhotoEditActivity("moizali");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: which device are you using ?

Comment: It is a Morolla device. with ICS as the OS installed

Comment: what is the resolution of image when you captured

Comment: Thanks sir...the camera resolution coming 2500 by 3400...I will have to reduce it...

Comment: don't reduce the quality just have a look on: how to handle the large Image Bitmap. just few line of code

Comment: or reduce the size of the Image resolution. Your choice both will working

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError while taking picture from camera using Base64 in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13471387/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-while-taking-picture-from-camera-using-base64-in-andr)